# Random Graph Python networkx Read file and plot graph

Tags: python, random, graph, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to read a file that has like 10000+ entries and with 3 columns. column 1 and 2 are the nodes and column 3 is the time in seconds. I am initially trying to plot a random graph G=(n,m) with the data and later want assign the data from 3rd column in between the two relative nodes. After that i have to count the number of nodes, edges, bridges in that graph. 
I am some what lost here. if i should first plot the graph and then do the counting or should i count and then plot the graph. Any suggestion will be helpful.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sy
import itertools as it
import time

with open("File.txt") as f:
     data = f.read()
     data = data.split('\n')
node_one = [row[0] for row in data]
node_two = [row[1] for row in data]
def draw_graph(graph): 
    G = nx.Graph()
    #G.add_edges_from([(node_one[0], node_two[1]])
    #G.add_edges_from(node_one, node_two)
    G.number_of_nodes()
    G.number_of_edges() 
    G.neighbors(edge[0], edge[1])
    n = nx.number_connected_components(G)
    bridge_count = 0
    for edge in G.edges():
        if len(set(G.neighbors(edge[0])) & set(G.neighbors(edge[1]))) == 0:         
           G.remove_edge(edge[0], edge[1])          
             if nx.number_connected_components(G) > n:                  
                print edge, 'is a bridge'
                bridge_count += 1
                G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
print number_of_nodes()

print number_edges()

print neighbors()

print bridge_count
```

The error i am getting here is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "edge_bridge.py", line 13, in

```
node_one = [row[0] for row in data]
```

IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
G.number_of_nodes()
G.number_of_edges()
```

can do the counting for you, they can be done separately than plotting the graph out.
Edge attributes can be added following the instruction [here](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#adding-attributes-to-graphs-nodes-and-edges).

What is your definition of a bridge here, an edge between 2 nodes that don't have common neighbors? For that, you can iterate through each edge and look for common neighbors of the two end nodes. If there is no common neighbor, that is a bridging tie.

If the definition of a bridge is an edge that when removed, yield more unconnected components, as mentioned by @mdml in the comments. You can do the same iteration as mentioned above, adding one more step. When there is no common neighbors, delete the edge from the graph, count the number of connected components, if the number increases, that's a bridge. Then remember to put the edge back to the graph before iterating to the next edge.
Something similar as below

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (5,6), (6,7), (5,7)])
n = nx.number_connected_components(G)
bridge_count = 0
for edge in G.edges():
    if len(set(G.neighbors(edge[0])) & set(G.neighbors(edge[1]))) == 0:
        G.remove_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
        if nx.number_connected_components(G) > n:
            print edge, 'is a bridge'
            bridge_count += 1
        G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
print bridge_count
```

The output is

```
(2, 4) is a bridge
(2, 5) is a bridge
2
```

Comment: In graph theory a bridge is an edge that when removed increases the number of connected components in the graph (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory))). I assume that's what the OP is talking about.

Comment: Thank you so much.. But the problem that i am facing is to load the data from file. its a very very big file with like 1000000+ lines can you suggest anything related to that please.

Comment: i don't understand your question, I am dealing with networks of ~1 million edges and it takes seconds to read in the file and construct the graph

Comment: Were you having problem with reading your raw txt file? What have you tried and what problem do you have? Post a couple rows and see what we can do from there?

Comment: I am having problem in loading the nodes from the file. with open("filename.txt") as f:
 data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n') node_one = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
node_two = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]. I get error :: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: paste a couple lines of your data file? looks like the row.split(' ') did not work, or at least some lines it doesn't split to multiple items. how about `try: (your thing) except: (print out the row)`, just to see what causes the error

Comment: @sophiadw I did update the code what exactly i am trying to run and also the error that i am getting ..If i uncomment this #G.add_edges_from([(node_one[0], node_two[1]]). I am getting Invalid Syntax error.

Comment: throw out the other codes that counts edges, nodes, or bridges, you are attempting too many things all at once. focus on read your txt file correctly. one thing at a time

Comment: try this first
`with open("File.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.split('\n')
    for row in data:
        print row`

Comment: @sophiadw File reads just fine but again while combining with the code above its same

Comment: as I said, do one thing at a time. don't combine a whole bunch of codes. try, did you parse your rows correctly?

Comment: @sophiadw As you said one thing at a time. I can read the file just fine and also plot a random graph. Now i have to find the neighbours of 2 nodes. I did find lot of information that shows neighbours of 1 node but i need to find the neighbours of the Pair of nodes.

Comment: `G.neighbors(n)` returns a list of nodes that are n's neighbors. If you want neighbors of 2 nodes, you can do `set(G.neighbors(n1))` and `set(G.neighbors(n2))`, then you can take the union, intersection, or whatever operation of the two sets to get the neighbors you want. Look at this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for python sets.